# Google Sheets: Selecting which sheet the column you want to select in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is there a way to manually select which sheet to select in query when you are importing multiple sheets?

for example i have the following data

```
spreadsheet 1(Animal Sheet)
header1 header2 header3
cat     white   10
dog     black   20
mouse   brown   30
duck    white   40
```

```
spreadsheet 1(Car Sheet)
header1 header2 header3 header4
honda   red     van     50
toyota  yellow  car     60
porsche pink    car     70
bmw     brown   suv     80
```

Spreadsheet 2
im using the formula

```
=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Animal'!A1:Z100");
    IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Car'!A2:Z100");
  },
  "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"
)
```

but with this formula it will show column 3 of spreadsheet 1(car sheet) which i want to be excluded

what i want to happen is

```
header1 header2 header3
cat     white   10
dog     black   20
mouse   brown   30
duck    white   40
honda   red     50
toyota  yellow  60
porsche pink    70
bmw     brown   80
```

combine both sheets but exclude column 3 in Spreadsheet 1(Car Sheet)

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
={
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Animal'!A1:Z100"),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL");
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Car'!A2:Z100"),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col4 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
}
```

- In this modification, the columns you want to retrieve are retrieved from each range using `QUERY`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the cleanest solution would be to align the columns you have in your spreadsheet `Car` to the ones of your spreadsheet `Animal`, like this:

```
header1 header2 header3 header4
honda   red     50      van
toyota  yellow  60      car
porsche pink    70      car
bmw     brown   80      suv
```

And then in your query have only the first 3 columns being called:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Animal'!A1:Z100");
    IMPORTRANGE("key-or-url-of-spreadsheet-1", "'Car'!A2:Z100");
  },
  "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"
)
```